# JavasScript/HTML5 application won't run anywhere other than on my pc despite being hosted externally on github

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've recently created a simple js application that functions as a children's colouring book which I have hosted with GitHub pages here http://leachrode.github.io/ . It works perfectly for me when I access it but from any other computer it seems to fail (lagging out and eventually producing a response a long time later if the tab it's been opened in doesn't die first) and I'm really not sure why that would be the case. The result was exactly the same when someone else attempted to host it on their server outside of GitHub.

The code is at https://github.com/leachrode/leachrode.github.io . I would try and post a relevant section here but I'm utterly lost as to what the relevant section is.

There is also a (I think although I may well be mistaken) separate issue when opening it in Firefox where the browser complains that the first argument to getImageData at line 198 is not a finite floating point value for reasons I also can't figure out:

```
    function pickUpColor(x, y) {
    var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    var ctx = gameCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var newColour = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);

    if (newColour.data[0] === 255 && newColour.data[1] === 255 && newColour.data[2] === 255) {
        var testColour = ctx.getImageData(420, 620);
        if (testColour.data[0] === 255 && testColour.data[1] === 255 && testColour.data[2] === 255) {
            curColour=[newColour.data[0],newColour.data[1],newColour.data[2]];
        }
    } else {
        curColour=[newColour.data[0],newColour.data[1],newColour.data[2]];
    }
    }
```

Which is called at:

```
function feedback(event) {
    var x = event.offsetX;
    var y = event.offsetY;

    if (y < 550 && !(y < 48 && x < 345)) {
        fastflood(x,y, curColour);
    } else {
        pickUpColor(x,y, curColour);
    }
}
```

edit: It appears the app simply doesn't work in firefox because it doesn't support offsetX or offsetY http://help.dottoro.com/ljjqvtaf.php or  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=547004 . As such I'm simply trying to get it to work in Chrome for now to figure out why it hangs when anyone runs it other than me

Comment: the implementation of your flood fill algorithm seems very inefficient. you read each pixel from canvas context. I usually get all pixels into memory and read from there.

Comment: I've altered the implementation to a more efficient one (caching all the data, working in memory and pushing once each flood is complete as you say). This seems to have solved the issue so I suspect that it was the source although I'm still a little bemused as to why it worked (a little slowly but reasonably well) from my pc but not for anyone else, despite being hosted elsewhere.

I thought that it may be an efficiency issue but was slightly blindsided by that strangeness.

Comment: how did you run it on your computer? did you have a web server or were you just running it by opening the file in the browser? I do not know why it was slow for everyone but for you. Maybe it has something to do with the security checks that browser does when a canvas context is accessed. I do not know.

Comment: I mean that it ran reasonably when I accessed the version uploaded on GitHub. That is a possibility though, during development I had --disable-web-security flagged on chrome (to bypass CORS issues when I was initially testing locally) which may have allowed GetImageData to occur much faster. Aah well, a mystery but one I'm not particularly concerned about solving now that it works reasonably well when other people access it